# extern "C" (C linkage) by default

Tags: c++, c, linker, extern, linkage

### Question

Do GCC, MSVC, or Clang, or some combination support setting linkage to default to C?

### Background

I have a large mixed C/C++ project, and while it's easy and logical to export symbols in the C++ sources with C linkage, those same sources are assuming the stuff in the rest of the project are under C++ linkage.

The current situation requires me to explicitly wrap anything the C sources use that is defined in the C++ sources and everything the C++ sources use from the C sources with `extern "C++"`.

To top things off, I can't put `extern "C"` around entire source or header files, as the actual C++ stuff will then complain. (Such as from `#include <memory>` or templates I've defined.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard pattern in a header file is:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus

// C++ stuff

extern "C" {
#endif

// C/C++ stuff

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I'm not sure you've got any other options.  The C/C++ stuff must be declared with C linkage everywhere.  The C++-specific stuff must be declared with C++ linkage everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

"C" linkage by default makes only sense for C sources, not for C++ sources, and vice versa. "C" linkage usually implies that names/symbols will not be mangled. "C" linkage is not expressive enough to be usable for C++ sources, e.g. for overloaded functions.